# PHP Uploading video not possible due to post_max_size

Tags: php, file, file-upload, video-upload

Im trying to upload from js to my php script a video that is 600Mb large, but `post_max_size` in php.ini won't let me do that. I have no access to this file due to webhosting provider and I cannot change it in .htaccess. Is there any way of kind of evading this limitation and still upload a file, that is larger than the setting in php.ini?

Comment: You should ask your hosting provider. If they say that is not possible, an alternative solution is to use virtual machine.

Comment: Provider said that it is not possible to change this limit.

Comment: Use [chunk upload](https://gist.github.com/ve3/9bc4ec3ee9bcce755c23bddbfce33306). Slice one big file into pieces and upload, once all files are upload completed then merge them.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set upload_max_filesize in script
   ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "600M")
2. Use chunk uploading

Comment: The problem is not in the `upload_max_filesize`, but in `post_max_size` and I thought you cannot change these settings. Aren't they used before even my php script starts so you cant change them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with **.user.ini** or **.htaccess** or **ini_set**(in your php script)

For me **.user.ini** works perfectly

1. Create a new file(0644 on Linux) **.user.ini** on your webspace/working dir with

   ```
   max_execution_time = 10000
   upload_max_filesize = 5000M
   post_max_size = 5000M
   ```

   This is my config file **.user.ini** on my webspace and it works.

   You can change the values to your needs.
2. Create a new file(0644 on Linux) **.htaccess** on your webspace/working dir with

   ```
    php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
    php_value post_max_size 1000M
   ```

   Don't forget the first dot/point at the beginning of the file.
3. Put this on the beginning of your php script

   ```
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '1000');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '1000M');
   ```

If this won't work(and you can't modify php.ini) than contact your webhoster and ask him, what you can do.